# Jersey @Consumes @Produces not accepted by the server ,

Tags: java, rest, tomcat6, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

I have the following class :

```
package test

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Path("/test")
public class test {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(test.class);



    @GET
    public Response getMsg() {
    logger.info("Inside getMsg()");

    String output = "hello world";

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

     @GET
     @Path("/get")
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public Track getTrackInJSON() {

         Track track = new Track();
         track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
         track.setSinger("Metallica");

         return track;
     }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) {
        String result = "Track saved : " + track;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

    }
        }
```

Track is just an object of another class

I have the following dependencies in my POM :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and this is my servlet mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Everytime I use the

BASEURL/rest/test  -> Correct response ( Hello world)

BASEURL/rest/test/get   -> Type:GET

response: `<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 - Error report</title></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Internal Server Error</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.42</h3></body></html>`

also in the tomcat execution I can see the error:

Jan 27, 2014 1:41:28 PM

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.myProj.jsp.rest.Track, and Java type class com.gsipartners.apimgmtut
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.myProj.jsp.rest.Track, and Java type class com.myProj.jsp.rest.Track, and MIM
        ... 24 more
```

I have no idea why this is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's having a problem writing the Track java object back in the response.

You don't appear to have Moxy in your POM. Do you have some form of JSON Marshaller in your classpath?

Have a look at this: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy